# How to list all Open Graph objects associated with a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I was using a Facebook developer tool called Object Browser to list Open Graph objects associated with my app. It was accessible from https://developers.facebook.com/tools, but seems to have disappeared today (May 7th 2019). Is there another way to list all the Open Graph objects associated with a Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question to Facebook support. The answer was that there is no way to do this anymore. Essentially you should keep track of the open graph objects yourself.

You can still get information about a specific Open Graph object if you know the URL that was scraped to create the object with the Object Debugger tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object.